# Why is jQuery appending stuff to the end of my AJax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this piece of code:

```
$.getJSON('http://domai.nr/api/json/search?q='+encodeURI(d.val())+'&callback=?','',function(data){...});
```

But I'm seeing this in my Google Chrome console:

```
GET http://domai.nr/api/json/search?q=google.com&callback=jQuery162020250764419324696_1323616418227&_=1323616456577 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: because you are encoding the uri... and that url + the uri is not being found be the server..

Comment: The `_=...` is because JSONP has `cache: false` set by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of `callback=?` is that jQuery will generate a pseudo-random unique function name and replace the question mark with it.

Otherwise you risk getting race conditions with JSON-P requests.